# How to solve this in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I solve the equation

[image: equation]

in Matlab to plot the curve between the imaginary part of `u` and `E`.
The parameters are given below:

```
u= a+ic, 
b= 0.05, 
zeta= 0.024, 
delta= 0.39, 
H=3, 
mu= 4*pi*1.e-7
```

where, `E` is in range between `(-2,2)`.

So in the plot, `E` would be on x-axis and the imaginary part of `u` would be on y-axis.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: What is the equation for E?

Comment: What is the unknown? Which variables are complex? Can you find an explicit expression for the unknown (manually)?